# Function to find a continuous sub-array which adds up to a given number in python

Tags: python, data-structures

I want to know what's wrong in the below code. Will it consume more time to in some certain scenarios?
Expected time complexity: O(n)

```
def subArraySum(self,arr, n, s):
   if sum(arr[0:n]) == s:
       return [1, n]
   if sum(arr[0:n]) < s:
       return [-1]
   start = 0
   i =1
   sum_elements = 0
   while i < n:
       sum_elements = sum(arr[start:i+1])
       
       if sum_elements == s:
           return [start+1, i+1]
       if sum_elements < s:
           i += 1
           continue
       if sum_elements > s:
           start += 1
           continue
           
   if sum_elements < s:
       return [-1]
```

Comment: No, you need to tell *us* what's wrong with the code. How is it called? What is the input? What is the output, if any? How is it different from what you expect? Are there any errors or tracebacks? If so, give us their [*full text*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146).

Comment: @MattDMo Hi Matt, thanks for your response. I gave this solution to a compiler which ran it against some test cases and few of them were taking more time to execute than expected by the compiler. The problem is that the compiler just gave me a hint that expected time complexity is O(n).

Comment: There seems to be an assumption that all array values shall be positive, or at least non-negative, but that doesn't appear in the code at all. Also, `sum(big_slice)` takes O(n) linear time, so putting that within a linear `while` loop gives O(n^2) quadratic running time. (Summing a fixed-size window, like `[i : i+3]`, can happen in O(1) constant time, but that's not what's happening here.)

Comment: @J_H Thanks. Looks like I should write some other logic instead of sum(big_slice), may be a while loop again on the sum.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of running `sum(arr[start:i+1])` in each iteration of the `while` loop, you should use a variable and add or subtract the respective value that is included or excluded from the subarray in each iteration. That way you can avoid the O(n^2) complexity and stay within O(n).

Currently there is a lot of overhead for calculating the sum of a (potentially large) subarray that has only changed by one single value at the beginning or the end during each iteration.